# HMAC authentication of secret and payload in Symfony 5.4

Tags: javascript, php, hmac, symfony5, hmacsha256

My JavaScript code is making the following `POST` API call to my endpoint:

```
const payload = {
   course: args,
   recipient: roomId
};
const signature = this.calculateSignature(JSON.stringify(payload), secret);

const response = await fetch(`https://crmpicco.co.uk/app/api/dsf7s9d8797987897987`, {
   method: 'POST',
   headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'X-EchoBot-Signature-256': signature 
   },
   body: JSON.stringify(payload)
});

calculateSignature(payload, secret) {
   return "sha256=" + crypto
   .createHmac('sha256', secret)
   .update(payload)
   .digest('hex');
}
```

in my Symfony 5.4 PHP app I have the following code:

```
$echoSecret = "0IQgWRFC1872i6AQc3mDo3Dc48UfWATPCoRX";

$encodedPayload = json_encode(json_decode($request->getContent()));
$calculatedSecret = hash_hmac('sha256', $encodedPayload, $echoSecret);
if ($headers['x-echobot-signature-256'][0] == "sha256=" . $calculatedSecret) {
    $this->getLogger()->info('The signature is valid, proceed...', [
        'calculatedSecret' => $calculatedSecret,
        'headerSecret' => $headers['x-echobot-signature-256'][0]
    ]);
} else {
    $this->getLogger()->info('The signature is invalid :(', [
        'calculatedSecret' => $calculatedSecret,
        'headerSecret' => $headers['x-echobot-signature-256'][0]
    ]);
}
```

Everytime I call the endpoint the authentication fails and falls into the `The signature is invalid :(` `else` block.

The request looks like this:

> "request":{"stdClass":{"course":["topaid33"],"recipient":"!LjZCWlshucBDhBobTT:crm.com"}},"payload":"{"course":["topaid33"],"recipient":"!LjZCWlshucBDhBobTT:crm.com"}","headers":{"accept-encoding":["gzip,
> deflate,
> br"],"content-type":["application/json"],"user-agent":["Amazon
> CloudFront"],"x-amz-cf-id":["ndCQJ9lvWATP_vSerFFFFaqHBhYqOn_wdSLF2vWBShXCBA=="],"x-cloudfront-key":["RFC1872"],"x-matrixbot-signature-256":["sha256=3577f59ea6f1dd44af8af2e9240093387897897987987a029ccf818ae92ee2cdb99"],"x-forwarded-port":["443"],"x-forwarded-proto":["https"],"content-length":["78"],"via":["1.1
> ip-10-82-2-81
> (Varnish/7.2)"],"host":["s.crmpicco.co.uk"],"x-varnish":["3735722"],"x-php-ob-level":["1"]

Where am I taking a mis-step here?

Comment: Are the two input data for the HMAC and the HMAC generated from it identical on both sides?

Comment: @Topaco They should be, yes. Would ordering have any effect here?

Comment: The HMAC works with bytes. It only returns the same value if the byte sequence is the same (value, number and order). For a JSON string, this means that the elements must also match regarding value, number and order. What's more, even the formatting (whitespaces etc.) and of course the encoding (e.g. UTF8) must be identical. It is best to compare the hex encoding of the (e.g. UTF8) encoded JSON string, which provides a 1:1 mapping of the bytes that are processed by the HMAC. This hex encoding must be the same.

Answer (score 0):

compare hashes using the `hash_equals` function

```php
$signature = $request->header('x-echobot-signature-256');

$computedSignature = hash_hmac('sha256', (string) $request->getContent(), $echoSecret);

hash_equals($signature, $computedSignature)
```